# Anchoring random numbers

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, random, amazon-redshift

Is there anyway to anchor a random number? I am using a random(). The script runs daily and adds new rows. I want the random number to stay consistent on existing rows and add a new random number on new rows. I am using Amazon Redshift DB, SQL.

```
Set seed42;
Select ID,
  random()
from existing table
where --parameters that populate the row--
```

Comment: Why do you need to *regenerate* the "random" numbers? Why not *store* them once generated? Will duplicates be a problem?

Comment: Why wouldn't you select the existing random value from existing rows and have the script use its own random function for new rows? Maybe more info on the flow would help. Are you inserting new rows or regenerating the whole table each time?

Answer (score 0):

I *think* what you want is to get the same random sequence each time. To do that you would set the "seed":

```
set seed to .25;
Select ID,
  random()
from existing table
where --parameters that populate the row--
```

However, I would assume that redshift (like most other databases) do not always return rows in the same order after new rows are added or deleted, or possibly after existing rows are edited. So this will probably NOT guarantee that the rows get the same random value each time you call the query. If you need that, I suggest that you save the "random" value in the data and just generate new random values for new rows.